# How to Redirect VueJS Frontend Route to Express Backend Route?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vue-router

I tried creating a BACKEND redirect route ('go' route, see below) that would redirect to links stored in my database by some ID. For example, I would have a link:

http://backend:3000/go/slug-name-of-post

The backend ExpressJS route looks like this:

```
router
  .route('/go/:slug')
  .get(controller.go)
```

Where the controller simply performs a redirect after it gets the URL form the database using the SLUG as the key:

```
   url = database.getUrlBySlug(slug)
   return res.redirect(url);
```

This part works great - I can type in backend url and it redirects just fine.

But now I am working on the VueJS FRONTEND and I want to include the links into my frontend webpage but I do not want this links to point to the BACKEND link directly - I want the links to be pointing to my FRONTEND instead. The main reason is that I want to be able to share these links and I want the link name to include my FRONTEND name instead of the BACKEND and the PORT number, etc.

For example, I want to link on my FRONTEND to be:

http://frontend/go/slug-name-of-post

And then I want the front end (Vue-Router??) to redirect to the correct back end, based on whatever the 'slug' is. Where 'slug' is defined in:  http://frontend/go/:slug

What is the best way to accomplish this? Do I simply create a Vue-Router route? If so, how do I have it redirect to a different webpage instead of to a component that is on the front end? Or do I need to create some component on the frontend that internally redirects to the backend?

The main issue is I don't want users to see the URL address of my backend when they see the links - or share the links, etc. I want the links to always point to my frontend, hence my frontend has to handle the initial routing. I guess I can have the frontend VUE component do a similar set of ExpressJS backend calls to get the final URL to redirect to and then do the redirect from the frontend?

Thank you in advance.